# How to create a 3D effect on asp.net grid

Tags: css, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net grid. I want to apply a 3D effect on the grid using CSS. Below is the CSS I am using currently. Is it possible to add CSS to the below CSS to achieve the 3D effect on an asp.net grid/html table?

```
.mGrid {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F1F7FE;
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

.mGrid td {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    color: #001131; /*word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word;*/
    /*border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #666 #DDD #DDD #666;
    padding: 3px;*/

}

.mGrid th {
    background-position: top;
    padding: 4px 2px;
    color: #1F364E;
    background: #B7D6FF url(../../Images/outlook/grid_head.png) repeat-x top;
    border: solid 2px #eeeeee;
    font-size: 0.9em; /*word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word;*/

}

.mGrid .alt {
    background-position: top;
    background: #D9EAFE repeat-x top;
}
```

Comment: What kind of 3D effect?

Comment: Hey Cedric , 3 D effect here means rich looking grid with more advanced css than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can sail around the problem that table cells behave a bit different than other HTML elements by using CSS3 `after` or `before` pseudo elements and put them on top of your `td`s.

```
.mGrid td {
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

.mGrid td:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #666 #DDD #DDD #666;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

[JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gm6eatvs/2/)